# Wrong logic in nested 'if' in a Python for-loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

I have a script to read an Excel file, which cells A1 ~ A6 contains:

```
OK 17
OK 9
BKK 17
OK 16
OK 12
BKK 16
```

They are the only contents of the Excel file.

What I want to do is to check the codes either ‘OK’ or ‘BKK’ is in the cell, and tell me whether the code in the cell is the same with that one row above.

For example, row 2 has ‘OK’, which is the same with row 1 has ‘OK’, so it shall tell me ‘OK found’ and ‘row no.2 and 1 found same code’.

However the result of running below skip some rows:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

the_file = open_workbook('c:\\file.xls',formatting_info=True)
the_sheet = the_file.sheet_by_index(0) 

for row in range(0, the_sheet.nrows):
    a = the_sheet.cell(row, 0).value
    above_a = the_sheet.cell(row-1, 0).value
    if a[0:2] == above_a[0:2]:
        print 'row no.' + str(row + 1) + ' and ' + str(row) + ' found same code'
        if 'OK' in a:
            print 'OK found'
        else:
            print 'BKK found'
```

As the result is:

```
row no.2 and 1 found same code
OK found
row no.5 and 4 found same code
OK found
```

The logic is wrong.

### Clarification

There are 6 values to be checked so I expect 6 results, however there are only 4. 2 were skipped.

It can be worked out like this but is there a way to simplify it?

```
for row in range(0, the_sheet.nrows):
    a = the_sheet.cell(row, 0).value
    above_a = the_sheet.cell(row-1, 0).value
    if a[0:2] == above_a[0:2] and 'OK' in a:
        print 'row no.' + str(row + 1) + ' and ' + str(row) + ' found same code' + ' OK found'
    if a[0:2] == above_a[0:2] and 'BKK' in a:
        print 'row no.' + str(row + 1) + ' and ' + str(row) + ' found same code' + ' BKK found'
    if a[0:2] != above_a[0:2] and 'BKK' in a:
        print 'BKK found'

    if a[0:2] != above_a[0:2] and 'OK' in a:
        print 'OK found'
```

Comment: The code prints the right stuff according to your description. What is missing? You don't print anything if a and above_a are not equal. Is that what you mean by skipping rows? Also, do range(1,brows) because the first row will never match.

Comment: thanks tdelaney. there are 6 values to go through but the results are only 4. I meant to have the 2 missing...

Comment: your outer if needs an else clause with a print statement. That'll show something for every row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure your code actually skips rows. You just don't print anything when a match isn't found. If you add an `else` to your outer `if` loop as follows:

```
from xlrd import open_workbook

the_file = open_workbook('c:\\file.xls',formatting_info=True)
the_sheet = the_file.sheet_by_index(0) 

for row in range(0, the_sheet.nrows):
    a = the_sheet.cell(row, 0).value
    above_a = the_sheet.cell(row-1, 0).value
    if a[0:2] == above_a[0:2]:
        print 'row no.' + str(row + 1) + ' and ' + str(row) + ' found same code'
        if 'OK' in a:
            print 'OK found'
        else:
            print 'BKK found'
    else:
        print 'row no.' + str(row + 1) + ' and ' + str(row) + ' do not match'
```

You should get the following results:

```
row no.1 and 0 do not match
row no.2 and 1 found same code
OK found
row no.3 and 2 do not match
row no.4 and 3 do not match
row no.5 and 4 found same code
OK found
row no.6 and 5 do not match
```

The bigger problem is that you are comparing a row with the row above by starting at the first row (because the range in the for loop goes from 0 to 5). So the first comparison is between "OK 17" and "BKK 16" (i.e. row 0 and row -1). You should be able to see this if you comment out the `if` loops and tell python to `print a, above_a` within the `for` loop.

```
for row in range(0, the_sheet.nrows):
    a = the_sheet.cell(row, 0).value
    above_a = the_sheet.cell(row-1, 0).value

    print a, above_a
```

In terms of row indices, you are comparing the following (a, above_a):

```
0 -1
1 0
2 1
3 2
4 3
5 4
```

You could fix this by starting at 0 and comparing with the row below, or more simply, start your `for` loop at 1. That would give you the following results:

```
row no.2 and 1 found same code
OK found
row no.3 and 2 do not match
row no.4 and 3 do not match
row no.5 and 4 found same code
OK found
row no.6 and 5 do not match
```

==================================================================================

To address your edit:

Your second version of the `for` loop does better in that it includes the cases where there is no match. But you still start your range at 0, so it is comparing the first row (index 0) with the last row (index -1). This is not ideal.

With regard to simplifying your if statements in the new `for` loop, you can use `elif` and `else` instead of four `if` statements. You can also change the last two `if` statements into a single `else` and nest an `if` to test if the row has a "OK" or "BKK" in it. The following code is an example:

```
for row in range(1, the_sheet.nrows):
    a = the_sheet.cell(row, 0).value
    above_a = the_sheet.cell(row-1, 0).value
    if a[0:2] == above_a[0:2] and 'OK' in a:
        print 'row no.' + str(row + 1) + ' and ' + str(row) + ' found same code' + ' OK found'
    elif a[0:2] == above_a[0:2] and 'BKK' in a:
        print 'row no.' + str(row + 1) + ' and ' + str(row) + ' found same code' + ' BKK found'
    else:
        if 'BKK' in a:
            print 'BKK found in row %d' % row
        else:
            print 'OK found in row %d' % row
```

There is a further issue to address. The above code only gives you 5 results. It sounds like you want to know two separate things:

1. Do the contents of a cell contain "OK" or "BKK"?
2. Do the contents of a cell match the contents of the cell above it
   with regard to the first question?

The issue you might be running into is that the first question involves 6 answers but the second question only involves 5. The first row doesn't have a row above it and thus doesn't have an answer to the second question. You might change the code to answer each question separately or to combine the two questions into a single print statement that includes a comparison for every row but the first one.

If I'm misunderstanding the problem you're trying to answer, please clarify further.

Comment: On preview, tdelaney said it more succinctly and quickly

Comment: ...but @user3684695 did the heavy lifting with an example and knew that row -1 wrapped to the other end of the cells, so I think (s)/he should get the win here.

Comment: thanks, user3684695. your spirit of helping and analyzing are highly appreciated!